# Nuance between 天, 空 and 大空 and between 地, 大地 and 土地

Tags: nuances

I was wondering the nuance between those words.

天 seems to have a more mystical flavour (like in the word 天上).

I don't get the nuance between 空/大空 and 地/大地.

土地 seems to be a smaller/more localised land than the other two.

**Feel free to edit my post and add any related word that seems relevant.**

Comment: I've always thought of 天 as "Heavens" and 空 as just "Sky".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

空 and 大空 both mean the same thing, but 大空 emphases the vastness of the sky. Analogous to that, 地 and 大地 mean the same thing, but 大地 stresses the size of the land/earth.

天 has a nuance of being distant to or above earth and it is the word you would used to contrast against it: 地と天. For that reason, it should not be surprising that it can also mean heaven.

A recommendation for the future: I personally think the goo 類語 dictionary is very great to quickly get an overview over the differences of similar words (I also used them for reference here), see [空(そら)／大空(おおぞら)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/12181/m0u/%E5%A4%A7%E7%A9%BA/) and [地(ち)／大地(だいち)／土(つち)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/12226/m0u/%E5%A4%A7%E5%9C%B0/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this dictionary looks really great indeed.